# How do I reset modal props on close

Tags: reactjs, redux, modal-dialog

I have a component, DeleteRoute, which is just a wrapper around a Modal. It allows me to delete a "Route" entity.

I am using React as well as Redux to maintain data and state.

I am struggling with the correct architecture to make the modal work.  I didn't like having all of the state in the parent container because it made the parent cluttered.  So I put the redux actions inside the modal. This way I pass in a route from the parent, but call "deleteRoute" from the redux store inside the DeleteRoute component, and I can display success and error messages.

This all works great, except it I close and re-open the modal, the previous success/error message is still displayed.  This is because the closing/opening is done with a toggle from the parent, but the parent can't reset the child props.

I thought I could just pass the success and error properties in the parent, and anytime the parent re-renders it would reset those, but it isn't (despite it re-rendering when isOpen changes).

```
class DeleteRoute extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.deleteRoute = this.deleteRoute.bind(this);
  }

  deleteRoute() {
    this.props.deleteRoute(this.props.route);
  }

  render() {
    var route = this.props.route || {};

    return (
      <div>
        <Modal
          isOpen={this.props.isOpen}
          toggle={this.props.toggle}
        >
          <ModalHeader toggle={this.props.toggle}>Delete Route</ModalHeader>

          <ModalBody>
            {this.props.isLoading && <Spinner color="primary" />}

            <Alert color="danger" isOpen={this.props.error}>{this.props.error}</Alert>
            <Alert color="success" isOpen={this.props.success}>Deleted successfully</Alert>

            <Form>
              <Row form>
                <Col>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="CssPlatform">Css Platform</Label>
                    <Input disabled name="CssPlatform" type="text" value={route.CSSPlatform} />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>

                <Col>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="ProdManager">Prod Manager</Label>
                    <Input disabled name="ProdManager" type="text" value={route.ProdManager} />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>
              </Row>

              <Row form>
                <Col>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="CssProduct">Css Product</Label>
                    <Input disabled name="CssProduct" type="text" value={route.CSSProduct} />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>

                <Col>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="ProgSupervisor">Prog Supervisor</Label>
                    <Input disabled name="ProgSupervisor" type="text" value={route.ProgSupervisor} />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>
              </Row>

              <Row form>
                <Col>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="CssSubProduct">Css SubProduct</Label>
                    <Input disabled name="CssSubProduct" type="text" value={route.CSSSubProduct} />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>

                <Col>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="RallyProject">Rally Project</Label>
                    <Input disabled name="RallyProject" type="text" value={route.RallyProject} />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>
              </Row>

              <Row form>
                <Col>
                  <FormGroup check inline>
                    <Label check>
                      <Input disabled name="CssProductActive" type="checkbox" checked={route.CSSProductActive} />
                      Css Product Active
                    </Label>
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>

                <Col>
                  <FormGroup check inline>
                    <Label check>
                      <Input disabled name="CssSubProductActive" type="checkbox" checked={route.CSSSubProductActive} />
                      Css SubProduct Active
                    </Label>
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </Form>
          </ModalBody>

          <ModalFooter>
            <Button color="primary" onClick={this.deleteRoute}>Delete Route</Button>{' '}
            <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.props.toggle}>Cancel</Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  state => state.deleteRouteReducer,
  dispatch => bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch))(DeleteRoute);


render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Routes</h2>
        <p>Routes define how items from CSS get imported into Rally. Use routes to connect a Rally project to a set of criteria in CSS.</p>
        <div>
          <AddRoute isOpen={this.props.showAddRoute} toggle={this.toggleAddRoute} />
          <DeleteRoute error={this.props.deleteRouteError} success={this.props.deleteRouteSuccess} isOpen={this.props.showDeleteRoute} route={this.props.selectedRoute} toggle={this.toggleDeleteRoute} />

          <DataTable
            actions={[
              { Click: this.toggleAddRoute, Color: 'green', Icon: 'MdAdd', ToolTip: "Add new route" },
              { Click: this.toggleEditRoute, Color: 'orange', Icon: 'MdEdit', ToolTip: "Edit route", RowAction: true },
              { Click: this.toggleDeleteRoute, Color: 'red', Icon: 'MdRemove', ToolTip: "Delete route", RowAction: true },
            ]}
            columns={[
              { Title: "Platform", Field: "CSSPlatform" },
              { Title: "Product", Field: "CSSProduct" },
              { Title: "SubProduct", Field: "CSSSubProduct" },
              { Title: "ProdManager", Field: "ProdManager" },
              { Title: "ProgSupervisor", Field: "ProgSupervisor" },
              { Title: "Product Active?", Field: "CSSProductActive" },
              { Title: "SubProduct Active?", Field: "CSSSubProductActive" },
              { Title: "Rally Project", Field: "RallyProject" },
              { Title: "Rally Url", Field: "RallyUrl" }
            ]}
            data={this.props.routes}
            edit={this.editRoute}
            isLoading={this.props.isLoading} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
```

Comment: You should extend your deletRoute action to also remove the errors from the state.

Comment: I put the error and success in props so Redux could set it.  So a "setState" in deleteRoute won't work.  Maybe I shouldn't control those from Redux?

Comment: Where do these errors/success messages live.

Comment: They live in props of DeleteRoute, they get set by Redux after an ajax call to an api.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up adding a redux action to reset the success and error props, and then calling that when the modal is closed.  I think this is in line with correct redux architecture, but I'm open to better solutions if anyone has them.

```
class DeleteRoute extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.deleteRoute = this.deleteRoute.bind(this);
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }

  deleteRoute() {
    this.props.deleteRoute(this.props.route);
  }

  toggle() {
    if (this.props.isOpen) {
      // reset the error and success messages on close
      this.props.initialize();
    }

    this.props.toggle();
  }

  render() {
    var route = this.props.route || {};

    return (
      <div>
        <Modal
          isOpen={this.props.isOpen}
          toggle={this.toggle}
        >
          <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>Delete Route</ModalHeader>

          <ModalBody>
            {this.props.isLoading && <Spinner color="primary" />}

            <Alert color="danger" isOpen={this.props.error}>{this.props.error}</Alert>
            <Alert color="success" isOpen={this.props.success}>Deleted successfully</Alert>

            <Form>
              <Row form>
                <Col>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="CssPlatform">Css Platform</Label>
                    <Input disabled name="CssPlatform" type="text" value={route.CSSPlatform} />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>

                <Col>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="ProdManager">Prod Manager</Label>
                    <Input disabled name="ProdManager" type="text" value={route.ProdManager} />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>
              </Row>

              <Row form>
                <Col>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="CssProduct">Css Product</Label>
                    <Input disabled name="CssProduct" type="text" value={route.CSSProduct} />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>

                <Col>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="ProgSupervisor">Prog Supervisor</Label>
                    <Input disabled name="ProgSupervisor" type="text" value={route.ProgSupervisor} />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>
              </Row>

              <Row form>
                <Col>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="CssSubProduct">Css SubProduct</Label>
                    <Input disabled name="CssSubProduct" type="text" value={route.CSSSubProduct} />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>

                <Col>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="RallyProject">Rally Project</Label>
                    <Input disabled name="RallyProject" type="text" value={route.RallyProject} />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>
              </Row>

              <Row form>
                <Col>
                  <FormGroup check inline>
                    <Label check>
                      <Input disabled name="CssProductActive" type="checkbox" checked={route.CSSProductActive} />
                      Css Product Active
                    </Label>
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>

                <Col>
                  <FormGroup check inline>
                    <Label check>
                      <Input disabled name="CssSubProductActive" type="checkbox" checked={route.CSSSubProductActive} />
                      Css SubProduct Active
                    </Label>
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </Form>
          </ModalBody>

          <ModalFooter>
            <Button color="primary" onClick={this.deleteRoute}>Delete Route</Button>{' '}
            <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggle}>Cancel</Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  state => state.deleteRouteReducer,
  dispatch => bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch))(DeleteRoute);
```

and the redux bits

```
import axios from 'axios';

// actions
const deleteRouteType        = "DELETE_ROUTE";
const deleteRouteFailureType = "DELETE_ROUTE_FAILURE";
const deleteRouteSuccessType = "DELETE_ROUTE_SUCCESS";
const initializeType         = "DELETE_ROUTE_INITIALIZE";

const initialState = { error: null, success: null };

// action creators
export const actionCreators = {
  initialize: () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: initializeType });
  },

  deleteRoute: (route) => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: deleteRouteType });

    axios
      .delete(`api/route`, route)
      .then(res => {
        if (res.data.error) {
          dispatch({ type: deleteRouteFailureType, payload: res.data.errorMessage });
        }
        else {
          dispatch({ type: deleteRouteSuccessType, payload: res.data.data });
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch({ type: deleteRouteFailureType, payload: err.message });
      });
  }
};

// reducers
export const reducer = (state, action) => {
  state = state || initialState;

  switch (action.type) {
    case initializeType:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: null,
        isLoading: false,
        success: false
      };

    case deleteRouteType:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: null,
        isLoading: true,
        success: false
      };

    case deleteRouteFailureType:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.payload,
        isLoading: false,
        success: false
      };

    case deleteRouteSuccessType:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: null,
        isLoading: false,
        success: true
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```